# FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() returns previously logged out user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have Android app which uses FirebaseAuth and FirebaseDatabase functionalities. Everything was working fine.

During last week I was working with one user (user 1) as an admin of the app and yesterday I registered another user (user 2) as a normal user(not admin).

Since all my admin functionalities were working fine, I never logged in as the user 1 again. However I had to uninstall my app today and by that time I was logged in as user 2.

When I reinstalled it again, I was automatically logged in as user 1 for some reason. So I logged out and logged in as user 2 again and uninstalled again. The same thing happened again and again.

I checked the user ID I am getting from the FirebaseAuth and its the user 1's user ID  which I had logged out previously.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
if(auth !=null)
{
    String uid = auth.getCurrentUser.getUid();
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue and I have added my logged out code below.

```
 AuthUI.getInstance()
    .signOut(ShopHome.this)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           // Code for login Activity              
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) which uses [Smart Lock](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/) to automatically log you in, even after after an uninstall of the app. If you do not want to automatically log-in, you can disable automatic sign in with Smart Lock.

Comment: It may help you during testing to ensure that you call [`AuthUI#signOut`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#sign-out), which prevents automatic log in the next time you start the app.

Comment: The problem is that it automatically log in as another user which I have already signed out using AuthUI.

Comment: So it seems the FirebaseUI-Android should be fixed to at least be able to cancel the smart locked log in. However, how can i avoid my device to use smart lock? I cannot turn off smart lock anywhere (4.4.2 and 5.1.1)

Comment: You should be able to disable SmartLock on your device by going to `Settings -> Google -> SmartLock for Passwords`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new emulator with a different device. This is the way I bypassed this issue.