# Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent() changes data in a different database node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had a firebaseAuth and FirebaseDatabse using Android App. I found out some issues with the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() returning a previously logged user after I uninstall and re install the app. I posted this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887007/firebaseauth-getinstance-getcurrentuser-returns-previously-logged-out-user)

However I also noticed that call to FirebaseDatabse addListenerForSingleValueEvent() callback listener changes some of the data in my database and it only happens when I uninstall and reinstall the app again. shown below is the code I am using to get the current user from the FirebaseDB.

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // already signed in
            mDatabase.getReference("users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                    new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                           // I commented the code here to check whether its coming from this part but it continued to occur even after commenting.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                        }
                    });
        }
```

As you can see I am accessing a node called users in the database by using user ID as the key and I am successfully getting the user data. However there is another node named "posts" in my database and I am using the same User IDs as the key. But the users and posts are two different nodes in the database.

So what happens is when the above addListenerForSingleValueEvent() is been called, some of the data under the corresponding user ID in the posts node changes. Right after a few seconds of the callback I can see some new data been removed from users post in red color and some been changed in yellow color.
When I commented the entire callback it was OK nothing changed or removed in posts.

AS I mentioned this only happens when I uninstall and reinstall again. I tried clearing cache without uninstalling and it was OK, I also tried clearing data and it was still OK.

I should also mention that I am using mDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true); and this issue only occurs when this is set to true. I tried commenting this line and everything was working fine.

Can anyone please help me as I am lost at this stage.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this is the only code interacting with Firebase Database? Adding a listener definitely shouldn't cause any other data in your database to change.  If you're sure there's no other code that could be doing the writes, can you enable logging with FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.Debug) at the beginning of your app and provide the output to Firebase Support?

Comment: yeah I commented out everything and just left this line and the issue was there. And when I comment this line it does not happen.

Comment: Very peculiar.  Can you send the logs I mentioned? You can just send them directly to me if you want (michael@firebase.com)

Comment: I was using it with Persistence not set for the last week because I didn't want my data to change. however when I turned Persistence true again this issue is not coming anymore.